# Database file not supported in Android studio

Tags: android

I am using Db browser for SQLite, I created .db  file in this  and store in asset folder of Android Studio but it shows file was loaded in the wrong encoding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to open a SQLite database in Android Studio. Android Studio does not have a built-in SQLite browser. Most likely, your file is fine, but do not attempt to open that file in the IDE.

Comment: LogCat shows this error: Couldn't open Sanjeevanidb.db for writing (will try read-only):
                                                                                com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/Sanjeevanidb.db file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable

Comment: @amoljunghare: You put the file in `database/`, and SQLiteAssetHelper is looking for it in `databases/` (note the plural).